# When was facebook.com launch in Vietnam?

Tags: facebook

I try to google for [this](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=when%20did%20facebook%20appear%20in%20vietnam&aq=f&oq=when%20did%20facebook%20appear%20in%20vietnam&aqs=chrome.0.57.6154j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=when%20did%20facebook%20appear%20in%20vietnam&oq=when%20did%20facebook%20appear%20in%20vietnam&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.106193.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c..12.psy-ab.bkQFn0Vm-iI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.bmk&fp=e7b598ecba95568d&biw=1813&bih=952) but I wouldn't find the answer.
When was it then?

Answer (score 2):

It appears Facebook never formally "launched" a Vietnamese site. Facebook [asked for users to help translate](https://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=20734392130) the site in June of 2008:

> Based on this feedback, we opened 55 new languages this week for
>   translation by the community. Now native speakers can use our
>   Translations application to translate Facebook into additional Asian
>   languages (Malaysian, **Vietnamese**), African dialects (Zulu, Xhosa),
>   regional varieties (British English, Canadian French) and even rarely
>   spoken languages, such as Latin and Esperanto.

And the Vietname version grew out of that. [This blog](http://harryd844.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/facebook-vietnamese-language-gaining-traction-how-can-vietnamese-facebook-clones-survive/) in October 2008 notes

> I recently checked the translation functionality of Facebook for Tiếng Việt (Vietnamese), and it was, well, really cool. The wording is quite accurate, and fits with the context of Vietnam.
>
> ....
>
> It was a surprise for me that Facebook in Vietnamese could go that fast without any fanfare.

So it appears within four months the site was translated to the point of being functional. But there was never any further announcement made, which is likely what made your search difficult.